# method run object iwshshell3 failed vba

Tags: vba, wscript.shell

I am trying to automate file upload on chrome with this VBA:

```
Dim Customer_rates As String

Dim WshShell As Object

Customer_rates = "D:\FX Exch. Rates\2022-Feb-24 1707\MP_customer_exchange_rates_sample.xlsx"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  
    WshShell.Run "cmd.exe/c echo" & Customer_rates & "| clip", vbNormal, True
    WshShell.SendKeys "^{v}"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("S", 2, Now)
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

I get this error:

> method run object iwshshell3 failed

Comment: Why would you bend over backwards to copy the filename to the clipboard and `.SendKeys()` CTRL+V, when you could `.SendKeys()` the actual filename?

Comment: you mean like this : WshShell.SendKeys Customer_rates in place of CTR+V? didnt work

Comment: Yes, exactly. A couple of characters have special meaning for SendKeys - you must escape `+`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `%`, `~`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)` as `{+}`, `{[}`, `{]}`, `{^}`, `{%}`, `{~}`, `{{}`, `{}}`, `{(}`, `{)}`, respectively - but other than that you can send the filename directly with `SendKeys` and skip the clipboard entirely. You could make a small helper function e.g. `Function MakeSafeForSendKeys(string)` that does these replacements and returns a safe value. Then you can call `WshShell.SendKeys MakeSafeForSendKeys(Customer_rates)` and it should work.

Comment: This function you could then re-use to directly type other values into other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how this would appear in the console.  The file path has spaces.  So it will require quotes around it when you run it.  Something like:

```
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe/c echo" & chr(34) & Customer_rates & chr(34) & "| clip", vbNormal, True
```

Comment: thanks but same error occurs again

Comment: Can you echo the output in the console and show us what command is being executed?

Comment: Yes thanks, here it is : 'D:\FX' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround of cmd with this Sub and it seems to work:

```
Sub StoreData()
  Dim varText As String
  Dim objCP As Object

  varText = "D:\FX Exch. Rates\2022-Feb-24 1707\MP_customer_exchange_rates_sample.xlsx"
  Set objCP = CreateObject("HtmlFile")
  objCP.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", varText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to always work with absolute paths (program and arguments).
Be aware of quotes. I preferably use chr(13)